# How to restore MiniAccumuloCluster using folder create previously

Tags: accumulo

I am trying to find a way to prevent the `MiniAccumuloCluster` from resetting every time i restart my code. I want to be able to keep my data from previous `MiniAccumuloCluster`. I thought it would be easy since it seems like the data is kept in one directory.

1. I tried to create one specific directory (instead of `createTempDirectory()`) and pass it on start, but I get an error that the directory is not empty.
2. Then I tried to hack it by creating a new directory then copy the content from my previous directory, but I get an error that the directory has already been initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature supported by MiniAccumuloCluster. MiniAccumuloCluster is intended to be used for testing during a build. If you want to quickly set up a single-node cluster of Accumulo, you might want to consider trying https://github.com/astralway/uno